# Primitive Pythagorean Triple: show a and b are coprime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, pythagorean-triples

Show $a$ and $b$ must be relatively prime where $a= m^2 - n^2$ and $ b = 2mn$. From this show that $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime. Show this
implies that $r$ and $s$ must be perfect squares as well.
$r = n^2$ and $s = m^2$.

I don't really know where to start here. I'm new with proofs. My first inclination is to plug $r$ and $n$ into $a$ and $b$, but this doesn't get me anywhere. Suggestions?

Comment: from where comes $r$, $s$?

Comment: What are $r,s$?  For the first part, suppose $a,b$ are not relatively prime...the square of gcd (a,b) will be a common factor of $a^2, b^2, a^2+b^2$ and $c^2$  Hence, not a primitive triple.

Answer (score 0):

Let $GCD(m,n)=f$  (a common factor) so that $(m,n)=(fx,fy)*emphasized text*$.

$$\text{ then }A=(m^2-n^2)= f^2x^2-f^2y^2=f^2(x^2-y^2)\quad \land \quad
 B=2mn=2fxfy=f^2(2xy)$$
$$\text{ then }(m,n)\text{ are co-prime if and only if } f=1 $$.
If any natural numbers are co-prime, then their squares are co-prime because they have no common factors to square as in the example of $GCD(3^2, 2^2)-1$.

$$\therefore GCD(m,n)=1\land r=m^2\land s=n^2\implies GCD(r,s)=1 $$